# C program to convert Decimal to Binary

Tags: c, string, algorithm, gcc, integer

I've written a program in C to convert Decimal numbers to Binary and store it in a string. The issue is not the binary that's printed in reverse but how the output is displayed

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int decimal;

    // get the decimal from user
    printf("Enter the decimal number: ");
    scanf("%i", &decimal);

    if(decimal == 1)
        printf("The binary equivalent of %i is %i\n", decimal, decimal);
    else
    {
        // considering binary is 64 bits in total
        char bit[64];
        int dividend, remainder, counter;

        // we need decimal value intact so dividend copies it
        dividend = decimal;
        counter = 0;
        do
        {
            remainder = dividend % 2;
            if(remainder != 0)
                bit[counter] = putchar('1');
            else
                bit[counter] = putchar('0');
            // update the dividend and counter
            dividend /= 2;
            ++counter;
            // break if dividend has reached 1
            if(dividend == 1)
                break;
          } while(dividend);

          // print the final result
          printf("The binary equivalent of %i is %s\n", decimal, bit);
    }

  return(0);
}
```

The output of 2 (that should be 01 in reverse) gives something like this
$ 0The binary equivalent of 2 is 0time
for decimal 3
$ 1The binary equivalent of 3 is 1time

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use the debugger `gdb`** so spend several hours learning how to use it. BTW your fix-my-code request is off-topic. And debugging is an essential part of programming activity.

Comment: What do you think `bit[counter] = putchar('1');` does? For a start, it **outputs** '1' and returns its ASCII value, but I don't think that is what you want (at least not the output part).

Comment: @MichaelWalz 1base10 = 1base2, 3base10 = 11base2. I don't mean that exact words on the console screen. So, if user key in 3 the output should be 11. 4 will be 001 (which is 100). But I want to keep the reverse the way it is.

Comment: @BenSteffan should strcat(bit, "1") be suitable?

Comment: @KeyikedalubeNdang No. Just write `bit[counter] = '1';`. I don't where your confusion about writing values to an array stems from, but since you don't seem to intent any side effects (such as writing the string to `stdout`), just saving the `char` value in the buffer is enough.

Comment: @KeyikedalubeNdang for clarification please edit your question and don't reply in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We beginners should help each other.:)

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    unsigned int decimal;

    // get the decimal from user
    printf("Enter the decimal number: ");
    scanf("%u", &decimal);

    // considering binary is 64 bits in total
    char bit[64];
    unsigned int dividend, remainder, counter;

    // we need decimal value intact so dividend copies it
    dividend = decimal;
    counter = 0;

    do
    {
        remainder = dividend % 2;
        bit[counter++] = remainder + '0';
    } while( dividend /= 2 );

    bit[counter] = '\0';

    // print the final result
    printf("The binary equivalent of %u is %s\n", decimal, bit);

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter the decimal number: 2
The binary equivalent of 2 is 01
```

As for your code then this code snippet

```
if(decimal == 1)
    printf("The binary equivalent of %i is %i\n", decimal, decimal);
else
```

is redundant.

This code snippet

```
        if(remainder != 0)
            bit[counter] = putchar('1');
        else
            bit[counter] = putchar('0');
```

does not make sense. As it is shown in the demonstrative program above what you need is to write

```
bit[counter++] = remainder + '0';
```

This exit from the loop

```
        if(dividend == 1)
            break;
```

is wrong.

You also need to append the resulted string with a terminating zero.

Also as you do not take into account the sign of the entered number then it is better to declare it as having type `unsigned int`.

Take into account that headers `<string.h>` and `<stdlib.h>` are redundant and may be removed.

Comment: Can I license this code with GPL in case I'm sharing it to my pals. Of course "Vlad from Moscow" will be the author... please?

Comment: @KeyikedalubeNdang You can use this code freely.:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
  if(dividend == 1)
```

to

```
  if(dividend == 0)
```

Also `memset` `bit` to 0 prior to using it ie `memset(bit,'\0',sizeof(bit));` before the loop

Comment: I made too many mistakes in my code. Vlad from Moscow pointed me out...:(
And yours did what I intended to do. Thanks :)